How can I check if there's a profile associated with an account when I check the JWT with spring-oauth2
I have implemented Spring-OAuth2 to authenticate user requests. But I also want the fronted to create a user profile in the database before I allow them to interact with the API.
So basically I want it to work like this for a new user
User creates firebase auth account=>user logs into firebase=>gets token=>user sends a request to the register endpoint=>a new profile object is created=>user sends requests to the api to access resources.
Here's the code for the JWT authentication:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    // ...

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                authorizeRequests
                    .requestMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer ->
                oauth2ResourceServer
                    .jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter()))
            );
        return http.build();
    }    
    private JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        JwtAuthenticationConverter converter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        converter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(new CustomAuthoritiesConverter());
        return converter;
    }
}
public class CustomAuthoritiesConverter implements Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {

    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt jwt) {
        if (jwt.getClaim("roles") == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        return jwt.getClaimAsStringList("roles").stream()
            .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

I was thinking of simply putting into the custom Authorities converter, but from the documentation it seems not the right place for it. I could just stick in front every api request controller, but it really seems it should simply be part of the api (althought obviously, it would need an exception for the register endpoint). So where can I put the callback to check if a profile object exists?

I believe that "a new profile object is created" is usually a part of  "User creates firebase auth account". Otherwise, creating a profile should be handled by the part of your code that receives the OAuth callback. As you say, handling this for every request in the resource server, does not feel right. BR

but don't I have to check on every request that the user actually has a usuable profile (with application specific profile data)? And even if I react to the OAuth callback on auth profile creation, it may still go wrong (for example if there's a network error or if the server was in maintenance)

The "user-service" should probably be provided by the authorization server (Firebase). If you can't attach the data you need about users to Firebase, use your own OIDC provider in front of it (or instead of it). Keycloak, Auth0, Spring Authorization Server are just samples.
